# How to toggle a button when another button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 sample buttons, and what I need is when a user clicks on the second button, the first button will change its text.

Please see sample below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#anchor-sample-btn').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#anchor-sample-btn').text();
    if (text === "On") {
      $(this).html('Off');
    } else {
      $(this).text('On');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://bbirdtools.netlify.app/_global-externals/scripts/3.4.1.jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="outline" id="anchor-sample-btn">On</button>

<p> When the second btn is clicked, the first btn should change to <b>On</b> if it's <b>Off</b>, and vice versa</p>

<button class="outline">When I'm clicked, toggle the first btn on/off</button>
```

Also, how do I disable the first button when it's clicked for 5 seconds to prevent double click?

EDIT:

When the first btn is clicked, it should still change text and be disabled for 5 seconds.

The second button is just an alternative to perform the same function of the first btn, so it should toggle the first on/off.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: PS button cannot have a `href`

Comment: Oh right, it was originally an anchor, but changed it to button to get an outline for the presentation. Forgot to remove it.

Comment: you have onclick function on a wrong button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, this is one way (not using jQuery).

```js
const $btnOne = document.querySelector('#button-one');
const $btnTwo = document.querySelector('#button-two');

let buttonOneIsOn = true;

$btnTwo.addEventListener('click', () => {
  buttonOneIsOn = !buttonOneIsOn;
  $btnOne.innerText = buttonOneIsOn ? 'On' : 'Off';
});

$btnOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
  buttonOneIsOn = !buttonOneIsOn;
  $btnOne.innerText = buttonOneIsOn ? 'On' : 'Off';
  
  $btnOne.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    $btnOne.disabled = false;
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<button id="button-one">On</button>

<p>When the second btn is clicked, the first btn should change to <b>On</b> if it's <b>Off</b>, and vice versa</p>

<button id="button-two">When I'm clicked, toggle the first btn on/off</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the quick answer. But can you please tweak it so that when the user clicks on the On/Off button, it still changes its text and disable it? The second button was intended as an alternative button. Apologies if I haven't included this my question.

Comment: @ixcode like that?

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @ixcode in that case please accept this answer so other users see that the question has been answered.

Comment: I will! Just waiting for the timer limit!

Comment: @ixcode did you accept the right answer?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Yay!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to just trigger the click on the first when the second is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // nothing changed here
  $('#anchor-sample-btn').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#anchor-sample-btn').text();
    if (text === "On") {
      $(this).html('Off');
    } else {
      $(this).text('On');
    }
  });
  
  // listener on second button that triggers first
  $('#button-2').click(function(){
     $('#anchor-sample-btn').click()
  })
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://bbirdtools.netlify.app/_global-externals/scripts/3.4.1.jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="outline" id="anchor-sample-btn">On</button>

<p> When the second btn is clicked, the first btn should change to <b>On</b> if it's <b>Off</b>, and vice versa</p>

<button class="outline" id="button-2">When I'm clicked, toggle the first btn on/off</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition, you could add them to the buttons with that have the same classes.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.outline');
const anchorBtn = document.querySelector('#anchor-sample-btn');
let btnOn = true;

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    let target = e.target;
    anchorBtn.textContent = btnOn ? 'Off' : 'On';
    btnOn = !btnOn;
    if(target.id === 'anchor-sample-btn'){
      target.disabled = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        target.disabled = false;
      },5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="outline" id="anchor-sample-btn">On</button>

<p> When the second btn is clicked, the first btn should change to <b>On</b> if it's <b>Off</b>, and vice versa</p>

<button class="outline">When I'm clicked, toggle the first btn on/off</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out which button should have onclick event and how you handle it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').on('click', function() {
    var target = $('#anchor-sample-btn');
    var text = target.text();
    if (text === "On") {
      target.text('Off');
    } else {
      target.text('On');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://bbirdtools.netlify.app/_global-externals/scripts/3.4.1.jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="outline" id="anchor-sample-btn">On</button>

<p> When the second btn is clicked, the first btn should change to <b>On</b> if it's <b>Off</b>, and vice versa</p>

<button id="clickme" class="outline" href="#anchor-sample-btn">When I'm clicked, toggle the first btn on/off</button>
```